# MYSQL SQL statement. Is this conditional query possible?

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

3I was just wondering if this type of query is even possible. If so, help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    SELECT 

        field1,
        field2,
        field3

    FROM maintable

    WHERE maintable.field1 = passed_in_parameter


    IF (maintable.field2 = 1) THEN
            //do anything like joins
        INNER JOIN widgettable on widgettable.widgetid = field3

    ELSEIF (maintable.field2 = 2) THEN
            //do anything like joins
        INNER JOIN gizmottable on gizmottable.gizmoid = field3

    END IF
```

I hope what i am trying to do makes sense.
In summary, I need to join different tables based on what a field value is in the original select.

Comment: You could `LEFT JOIN` them both

Comment: No, it's not valid SQL syntax.

Comment: Do you want to select anything from widgettable or gizmotable?

Comment: @Amit Bhargav - I need widgettable.widget_name or gizmotable.gizmo_name

Comment: I think you can do a `INNER JOIN widgettable on widgettable.widgetid = field3 AND maintable.field2 = 1 INNER JOIN gizmottable on gizmottable.gizmoid = field3 AND maintable.field2 = 2`

Comment: @gbroke OK. Have updated my answer to include this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As zerkms suggested, you can left outer join them both. Please see if the following works

```
select mt.field1,
    mt.field2,
    mt.field3,
    CASE mt.field2 WHEN 1 THEN wt.widgetname WHEN 2 THEN gt.gizmoname END AS name 
from maintable mt
  left join widgettable wt
    on wt.widgetid = mt.field3
  left join gizmotable gt
    on gt.gizmoid = mt.field3
where mt.field1 = 'param'
   and ((mt.field2 = 1 and wt.widgetid is not null)
       or (mt.field2 = 2 and gt.gizmoid is not null))
```

Comment: Just curious why do you add `OUTER` in mysql?

Comment: @zerkms Ah my bad... I don't normally use mysql. Forgot that outer could be omitted. Thanks!

Comment: nono, mysql ignores it. So you just use another DB that differs them. That's what I asked about :-)

Comment: @zerms Yeah I normally use Oracle

Comment: @Amit Bhargava looks like you changed it from your original post. I tried the first one you had, with the 'outer' and without the CASE statement. That's the one that worked.

Comment: @gbroke I added the case because we needed name as well and as zerms pointed out outer is redundant in MySql. Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Amit Bhargava I am using MYSQL 5. I did wt.widget_name as widgetname,gt.gizmo_name as gizmoname in the select. It worked but brought back an empty field sometimes, so the CASE seems to solve that. Works perfect, thanks again! I learn something everyday. Well, at least when I ask for help. :)

Comment: @amit: perhaps you made a typo on the last line, may be you meant `mt.field2 = 2 and gt.gizmoid is not null`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    maintable.field1,
    maintable.field2,
    maintable.field3,
    CASE maintable.field2
    WHEN 1 THEN widgettable.widget_name
    WHEN 2 THEN gizmotable.gizmo_name
    END AS consolidated_name
FROM      maintable
LEFT JOIN widgettable ON widgettable.widgetid = maintable.field3
LEFT JOIN gizmottable ON gizmottable.gizmoid  = maintable.field3
WHERE     maintable.field1 = 'passed in parameter'
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Even though a different response worked, i will also try this and report back for anyone reviewing this page. I was curious about the CASE WHEN. I have never used it.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds a bit like a UNION query, except you've not specified that you want to see any data from the joined tables.  That means that the inner joins are simple existence checks; they check that there is a row in the joined table that matches the row in the main table.  I've taken the 'radical' step of assuming you want a couple of columns from the joined tables; you can omit those joined columns without seriously altering the overall effect.  This UNION query assumes that the columns you need from WidgetTable and GizmotTable are sufficiently similar.  Then you can write:

```
SELECT m.field1,
       m.field2,
       m.field3,
       w.column1,
       w.column3
  FROM maintable   AS m
  JOIN widgettable AS w ON w.widgetid = m.field3
 WHERE m.field1 = passed_in_parameter
   AND m.field2 = 1

UNION

SELECT m.field1,
       m.field2,
       m.field3,
       g.attribute23,
       g.attribute19
  FROM maintable   AS m
  JOIN gizmottable AS g ON g.gizmoid = m.field3
 WHERE m.field1 = passed_in_parameter
   AND m.field2 = 2
```

The direct analogue of what you're seeking is:

```
SELECT m.field1, m.field2, m.field3,
  FROM maintable   AS m
  JOIN widgettable AS w ON w.widgetid = m.field3
 WHERE m.field1 = passed_in_parameter
   AND m.field2 = 1
UNION
SELECT m.field1, m.field2, m.field3,
  FROM maintable   AS m
  JOIN gizmottable AS g ON g.gizmoid = m.field3
 WHERE m.field1 = passed_in_parameter
   AND m.field2 = 2
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Even though a different response worked, i will also try this and report back for anyone reviewing this page.